# Is there a way to make Google Chrome Frame work for Facebook Canvas Apps?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-frame

Not sure how to get Google Chrome Frame working for a Facebook Canvas App.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">
```

With this, chrome frame works fine when the page is loaded outside of the Facebook iframe container (the canvas url) - however it fails to load when the app loads inside Facebook - like all FB canvas apps.

Is there a way to make Google Chrome Frame work for Facebook Canvas Apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP then just write the line below at the top of your page it start working in every browser

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
```